# Is it possible to add horizontal scrollbar in tabulator for frozen row with resizable columns

Tags: tabulator

I have a table with 1 row which is frozen in tabultor, I have added the feature of resizing the columns size, but while expanding the column size , if it goes out total width, is there a way to add horizontal scrollbar for the frozen row as well.

I am able to scroll horizontally in case of multiple rows present with 1 frozen row.

Answer (score 0):

When the width of the row exceeds the width of the table, Tabulator will automatically add a horizontal scroll bar to the bottom of the table.

This scrollbar will also scroll the frozen row. Because the column headers must align with the rows and cells beneath them, there is no way to have a separate scroll bar for just one row, it would corrupt the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

use this css is your custom css

```
 .tabulator {
      overflow: scroll !important;
      width: auto !important;
      max-width: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).